# Django url reverse and regular expression

Tags: python, django, reverse

I got this in my urlpatterns `url(r'^(page/(?P<page>\d+)/)?$', 'index', name = 'index_path')`

and here is my views.py file

```
def index(request, page=1):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published = True)
    paginated_posts = Paginator(posts, 20)

    try:
        target_page = paginated_posts.page(page)
    except EmptyPage:
        return redirect(reverse('index_path'))

    response_dict = {
        'posts': target_page.object_list,
        'page': target_page,
        }

    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', response_dict)`
```

I use this for simple pagination, if user enters nothing ex '/blog/' return him/her first page, else return him/her page which he/she want.

Its working. But there is a problem when I want to use reverse() function.

When I type in interactive shell:

```
reverse("index_path")
```

I got:

```
 '/blog/'
```

But I do this:

```
reverse("index_path", args=(1, ))
```

I got error which says:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index_path' with arguments '(1, )' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

PS: in my master urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/', include('app.posts.urls')),
```

Comment: I presume in your urlpatterns at the top you mean `blog/` rather than `page/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in order to make this work properly you'll have to have two urls:

```
url(r'^page/(?P<page>\d+)$', 'index', name = 'index_path_page'),
url(r'^$', 'index', name = 'index_path'),
```

Then when you reverse, you have two options:

```
reverse('index_path_page', args=[1])
# or
reverse('index', args=[1]) # pulls by the name of the view.
```

The second is not recommended, but could certainly lead to easier logic in places.

Comment: It works properly. But I dont understand why I can't use one url pattern for that?

Comment: Basically reverse isn't that smart. It doesn't have a full regex parser and therefore can't deal with optional paramaters.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the URL regular expression.

```
r'^(blog/(?P<page>\d+)/)?$'
```

(Assuming you meant `blog/` rather than `page/`.)

This contains two groups.

- `(blog/(?P<page>\d+)/)` which is unnamed and thus $1
- `(?P<page>\d+)` which is named as "page".

You don't want to capture the first group there, so you should use `(?:...)` rather than `(...)`.

So then, try using `^(?:blog/(?P<page>\d+)/)?$` as your match regular expression. Then, try `reverse('index_path', kwargs={'page': 1})`.